# How to declare a matrix in .ned file

Tags: omnet++, inet

In OmNet++ 5.5.1, I want to initialize a matrix in .ned file.

In each run, some element values of the matrix will be updated and the updated matrix needs to be used in the following run. For example:

in .ned file,

```
matrix table={ {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };
```

in mac.cc file,

```
table[m][n] = table[m][n] + inc_rate;
```

If m , n = 1, and inc_rate = 1, after the first run, the updated matrix will be

```
matrix table={ {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} }
```

For the next run, the above value will be the initial value of the matrix and so on.

Would anyone please suggest me how I can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Runs are independent of each other and cannot modify the parameters of an other run. This is by design, because they can be run parallel where there is no particular order between them. You can hack around this, by creating a very simple INI file fragment that contains only the single line that defines the matrix and include that line in your omnetpp.ini file. Then, at the end of each run, you delete that file and write out a new file with the updated matrix.

How you create that matrix, is up to you. I would probably create a bash or python script that handles the matrix generation and then starts the simulation.

Comment: Rudi, I'm trying to implement machine learning in link layer. For learning, I may need at least 1000 episodes. After each run, manually deleting a file and again writing out a new one would be a very lengthy process. Do you have any other suggestions to implement it? Many thanks!

Comment: I've never said, you should do it **manually**. Obviously, you would delete/overwrite that particular file in some module's `finish()` method **from your code**. Writing out a one line file is well below 1ms, so it would not matter (compared to the length of a full simulation run). That way, even if a run fails, you could continue from there instead of re-running all the simulation runs from scratch...

Comment: BTW: we did a neural network based link layer error prediction experiment, if you are interested: https://docs.omnetpp.org/articles/neuralnet-errormodels/ But we just generated a ton of learning data first, and the nn learning was done in a separate step after that.

Comment: Thanks Rudi. Would you please suggest me how to  create a very simple INI file fragment that contains only the single line that defines the matrix? I have no idea  how to do that neither was able to find any example to look at. Please help.